# Copy the manual to clipboard

Tags: bash

I'd like to copy the manual to clipboard

```
In [25]: !man scp > scp.md
In [26]: !pbcopy < scp.md
```

I desire some commands like

```
In [24]: !pbcopy < man scp
/bin/bash: man: No such file or directory
```

Which get the manual copied directly.

How do I accomplish such a task?

Comment: You can just pipe it in.  Like `man scp | pbcopy`.  See also [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/15866/22523) for how to get rid of repeated characters in the output.

Comment: ty, could you please transmit the short comment to the answer. @GrishaLevit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pbcopy` accepts its input on stdin so you can just pipe to it, like

```
man scp | pbcopy
```

You may also want to filter the `man` output to remove some formatting that does not work in plain text, like:

```
man scp | col -b | pbcopy
```

<sup>Info from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/15866/22523)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `xclip`

```
man scp| xclip`
```

To get what is on your clipboard use `xclip -o`

```
xclip -o>scp.md
```